# Safari Browser Not Reading Css

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, safari

My website is working perfectly fine on Chrome/Firefox browser but it's responsiveness and everything is getting messed up on safari browser.

I think the reason behind this is misreading of CSS file which contains media queries.

As I have a windows device I cannot figure out what's going wrong, because I cannot check the console in safari browser.

http://raconmarine.com

Here are the screenshots of what it looks like on [chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIDlo.jpg)

And here's what it looks like on [safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwsbF.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Your nav bar]

I haven't looked for very long but in your HTML you have some extra blank spaces in your navbar. It doesn't affect you in Chrome if you delete it but it does affect you if you delete it in Safari. I removed if from your code in Safari and then toggled the css (float: left) and your navbar fit.

[image]

Can you remove those empty spaces from your HTML (as long as you verify it does not break anything) and then make those changes live. I can double check it in safari and see if that solves the solution on the initial load.

Comment: Thanks! Works for me. :)

Comment: ah :D wonderful! I am glad it worked~ If there is anything else let me know